# How to install cmake 3.14 on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, cmake

My version of Ubuntu is 18.04,I want to install the latest version of Cmake.However,I just can find the example on Ubuntu 16.04.Because I am a beginner,I want to know if I could follow the example.What's more,I want some detail information.
I will be grateful if you can help me.

Comment: Pretty sure this is available from the repository - `sudo apt install cmake`

Comment: A later version for 18.04 may be available from the cmake author https://apt.kitware.com/ ... ( Ubuntu provides version 3.10.2 https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/cmake )

Answer (score 9):

There is two options. First one: Just compile it from the source.

1. Install packages:

> `apt install build-essential git`

2. Get the source code:

> ```
> git clone https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/; cd CMake
> ```

3. Compile and install:

> ```
> ./bootstrap && make && sudo make install
> ```

Now you have cmake installed in your system (system wide) as a local version. You're done!

The other option is to use conda (of miniconda/anaconda), which is essential in managing Python library versions as separate enviroments. Assuming you have conda installed:

1. Create a new conda enviroment "CMake" and install cmake to it:

> ```
> conda create -n CMake cmake
> ```

2. Activate this environment:

> ```
> source activate CMake
> ```

Now you have cmake installed in an conda enviroment stored within your home directory, available after executing 2. from above. You're done! This second option does not require root/sudo privileges.